# How to increase the size of elegant themes icons?

Tags: html, css, icons

I've not used [elegant themes](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/how-to-use-and-embed-an-icon-font-on-your-website) icons previously. I've tried their website and a few other searches but haven't so far been able to determine how to simply increase the size of the icons I'm using. I was wondering if anyone can help me please with the html for increasing the size of ET icons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use (font-size) in css style.
example:

in CSS
`.big { font-size: 180px; }`

in HTML
`<span class="icon-happy big"></span>`

Comment: Point taken @Yunnosch. Thanks for the advice.